# Bash: replace text in nth line of file with nth index of array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

Trying to replace MAC Addresses in a flat file. In the code below, the addresses are successfully mapping to the array. I've tried to use a counter to increment the array index on each loop, with the intent of replacing the address on line *n* with the *n*th address in the array.

The sed block effectively replaces the addresses, but only with the entry at array index *0*.

```
mapfile -t Arr1 < <(text processing commands)

i=0  
while read line 
do
  sed -E "s/([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}/${Arr1[$i]}/"
  ((i++))
done < $macFile
```

Comment: Example input/output/expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sed` is reading from standard input, so instead of reading the contents of the `$line` variable, it's reading the contents of the file designated by `$macFile` (except the first line, which has already been grabbed by `read`).

To fix this, add `<<< "$line"` to the end of your `sed` command.